# Node Js installation on CentOS - ImportError: No Module named bz2

Tags: python, node.js, centos

I'm trying to install Node on my CentOS server but it's giving me below errors when I run make

```
import bz2
ImportError: No Module named bz2
```

I installed bz2 using yum and it seems it's installed and also python version is 2.7.3

Why is this still coming up with this error then?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure if you are trying to install the Python or Node module.

For the Python module, try using `easy_install`

```
sudo easy_install bz2
```

For Node, try looking at the `npm` packages.

Answer (score 2):

Python is probably configured in the absence of bzip2-devel package. 
If that is the case, then install bzip2-devel package on your system using yum. And, then re-configure & install python.

Thereafter try installing node.
Thanks to  Steve Johnston from this  [link](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.javascript.nodejs/38717). I felt so frustrated and relieved at the same time when I read that line.